# How fix cors request for socket.io and webpack proxy?

Tags: sockets, webpack, socket.io, proxy, cors

I trying to connect socket.io client to my nest.js server on default socket path `http://localhost:3000/socket.io`

But also I want to add extra headers for sending auth token, but when I adding extra headers, how I understand I just rewriting webpack proxy headers, how I can pass extra header for socket.io and correct use wepback proxy?

**socket.io version 2.4.0**

```
this.socket = new Manager(`http://localhost:3000`, {
      transportOptions: {
        reconnectionAttempts: 10,
        polling: {
          withCredentials: true,
          extraHeaders: {
            'authorization': token,
          }
        },
      },
 });

this.socket.socket();
```

**webpack proxy config**

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
      'socket.io': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        changeOrigin: true,
        ws: true,
        router: {
          // when request.headers.host == 'dev.localhost:3000',
          // override target 'http://www.example.org' to 'http://localhost:8000'
          'http://localhost:3000': 'http://localhost:8000',
        },
      }
    }
  },
```

And that all headers with extra headers
[image]

And without extra headers

[image]

Comment: Hey man, I'm having the same issue proxying socketio to a node backend with webpack. Did you ever fix this?

Comment: @JudeDesir I just added hot fix, with auth by first query in handshake reqeust

Comment: Okay, this might seem like a silly question, but where does the value 'token' come from? That's what you're referring to, right? In the extraHeaders object? In the image that looks like just a JWT token?

Comment: @JudeDesir yes, token its JWT token